# Tkinter user input

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Trying to get clients input and make a search google

Example:

> client's  input entry = business emails
>   output = opens a new tab in
>   chrome > searches google for,   "intext:gmail.com business emails"

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser
root = Tk()
def main():
        global userInput
        root = Tk()

Label2 = Label(text="GhostTest")
Label2.pack()

userInput = Entry(bd=2)
userInput.pack()

Button1 = Button(text="Search,", command=userInput)
Button1.pack()


def GoogleSearch():
        new = 2
        userInput = Entry(bd=2)
        term = Entry(userInput)
        tabUrl = "http://google.com/?#q="
        webbrowser.open(tabUrl+str(term.get()),new=new);

root.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you get error message or what ? If you get error then put full error message.

Comment: Updated with correct indentation, the problem I am having is, It's just not doing anything when I hit the search button

Comment: first you should say it in question.

Comment: Very, very, new to python. My other lang I did was lua. So what do you mean?

Comment: At least part of the problem is that you're creating two root windows. In a normal Tkinter program you must have exactly one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: Hi. If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign function name (without parenthesis) to `command=`

```
import tkinter as tk
import webbrowser

# --- functions ---

def google_search():
    new = 2

    # get user input
    term = user_input.get()

    tabUrl = "http://google.com/?#q="
    webbrowser.open(tabUrl+term, new=new);

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(text="GhostTest")
lbl.pack()

user_input = tk.Entry(bd=2)
user_input.pack()

# run `google_search` on button click
btn = tk.Button(text="Search", command=google_search)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Worked, thank you and I will read and find out how this works.